# How to use comma as text input in html input array

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I want to pass comma in input field to server using input arrays. The server gets comma-separated input values from array of inputs and if an input contains comma as a text then it considers that comma as separator.

Example:

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" name="abc[]" value="1,2" />
<input type="text" name="abc[]" value="3,4" />
```

ASP.NET Server side code:

```
string[] ArrayOfInputs = Request.Form["abc[]"].Split(',');
```

gives me "1,2" as ["1", "2"] etc.

How to avoid this and get ["1,2", "3,4"]

Comment: What do you get from `Request.Form.GetValues("abc")`?

Answer (score 4):

Use this instead:

```
Request.Form.GetValues("abc[]");
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to Split the result of the request.
Just get the value

```
Request.Form.GetValues("abc[]");
```